# Kubernetes resource request relative to node resources

Tags: kubernetes

HPA needs the pod has resource request defined in order to calculate metrics to know when to schedule new pods.

Is there a way to specify that the CPU request of a pod is the 75% of the node resources? Like if the machine has 4 cores, it should use `cpu: 3`, and if the machine has 8 cores, it should use `cpu: 6`.

I would like to be able to scale up the node fleet without having to change the kubernetes definitions.

Comment: it's impossible in k8s. Requests are for scheduling to a one of the node all over the cluster where that that type of a resource is available to place the pod. You cannot say "this pod requires 75% of a node something" just because 75% is about nothing from node to node. Somewhere 75% is X, somewhere 75% is Y. The scheduler counts values, not percents

Comment: Is not possible, the closest thing available on k8s today is setting resources requests and limits in each container within a pod. But the units are not in %. You can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) to understand.

Comment: Guys, would any of you consider to convert your comments into the answer? They are pretty much solving the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm placing this answer for better visibility for community. As already stated in the comments  this is not possible. Fix percentage request might be problematic since it will request every time the same amount of resources when being scheduled to a node. But nodes can be different from each other hence you might get yourself in situation where one pod will request 75% cpu  of `node-1` which has 16 cpu and in another situation the pod will request the same amount of `node-2` which has on 4 cpu. This makes the value very inconsistent across node pool and not very specific. For that very reason Kubernetes uses `milicores` to request resources.

This was well described in the comments above:

> "Somewhere 75% is X, somewhere 75% is Y"   – [Konstantin Vustin]

You can read more about resources [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/).